# VBScript For Loop not executing if statement?

Tags: for-loop, asp-classic, vbscript, conditional-statements

Not exactly sure how to search for this issue I have with VBScript, so please forgive if this is a duplicate.

I have a function that prints pagination on a page that takes 2 parameters, `totalpgs` and `active`. My issue is that the `active` page only applies the style on the link when the variable `pg` is **NOT** set. I'm pretty sure this is a logic issue but I've been staring at this for 7 days now.

## Here is the function:

```
'======= Print Pagination links
function print_pagination (totalpgs,active)
    p = "<div class=""row"">"
    p = p & "<div class=""pagination pagination-right"">"
    p = p & "<ul>"
    for x = 1 to totalpgs
        if x = active then
            li = "<li class=""active"">"  '<- Set class for current page
        else
            li = "<li>" '<- else regular link
        end if
        p = p & li & "<a href='?pg="& x &"'>"& x &"</a></li>"
    next 
    p = p & "</ul></div></div>"
    print_pagination = p
end function
```

## Here is the code on the page:

```
pg = request.querystring("pg")
if pg = "" then
    pg = 1
end if

<%=print_pagination(totalpages,pg) %>
```

## Here is the desired result:

[image: Desired result is graying out the current page.]

I want the current `<li>` to contain a class called `active`.

## This is what's happening:

[image: The active class is never getting applied.]

The `active` class never gets applied to the `<li>` tag. When the url contains the get variable of `pg`, no active class is assigned. When it does not, then it's applied to the first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line that does the comparison to this:

```
    if cstr(x) = cstr(active) then
```